# ruby - how to assign a value to 2 variables at once

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am doing:

```
@var1=@var2='abc'
```

Is there a shorthand, something like `@var1,@var2='abc'` that would avoid the use of the 2 `=`'s which seem a bit clumsy.

Comment: using a comma instead of a equal sign is shorthand :) ? the way you suggest to me says only var2 gets the values from a C point of view but then its missing the type :)

Comment: You can write `@var1, @var2 = 'abc', 'abc'` but then you will have `'abc'` two times...

Comment: As is, this is the normal and expected way to assign a single value to multiple variables. You can't do it more cleanly and clearly and anything else is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@var1,@var2=["abc"]*2
p @var2,@var1
# >> "abc"
# >> "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently doing it the right way...

Two `=` isn't clumsy. It evaluates from right to left as it should...

```
>> a = b = :c
=> :c
>> a
=> :c
>> b
=> :c
```

But if you really want to avoid them, you could repeat yourself and use this, for instance:

```
>> a, b = :c, :c
=> [:c, :c]
>> a
=> :c
>> b
=> :c
```

Comment: Also note that he has an array there, so he might not want to end up with two variables pointing to the same object.

Comment: +1 to compensate :-), we have some strange crowd on SO tonight